# Why is iPhoto changing the titles of my photos after uploading the files to Flickr?

Tags: photos.app

After uploading photos to Flickr via the iPhoto "share" button, I find that iPhoto renames the photo titles to whatever I have in the description field. It'll then pass along those changes to Flickr.

I like to change my titles to something short before uploading, but this overrides either my custom titles or the ones the camera assigns.

Does anyone know how to turn this "feature" off? I'm using iPhoto 9.1.5 (that's iPhoto '11) under OSX 10.6.8.

[image]

Comment: No, you are not stuck with iPhoto. See Anthony Green's answer above:"to avoid this....."

Comment: Anthony also indicates that if I disable this, it'll remove the photos from flickr. This isn't an option for me.

Comment: You could try using the free Uploadr BEFORE disabling the iPhoto feature.  At worst, you will have 2 albums with the same pictures on Flickr until you disable iPhoto.

Comment: Will this affect the photos I have up there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be turned off. Another effect this has is that if you delete a photo in iPhoto, it also gets removed from Flickr.

To avoid this, i use Flickr's free [Uploadr](http://www.flickr.com/tools/uploadr/) rather than the built in tool. This lets you select the photos, give custom names, etc. It's easy to use, and if you make changes to the photos in iPhoto, there will be no effect on the images on Flickr.

Comment: How do I disable the built-in iPhoto uploader?

Comment: Go to Preferences > Accounts, select the Flickr account, and then click the - (minus) button at the bottom of the screen. This removes the account, and will stop photos being posted to Flickr. However, it will also remove any photos you previously added to Flickr through iPhoto.

Comment: Wait, it'll remove them from Flickr? So, if I want to maintain the photos on my Flickr account, I'm stuck using iPhoto?

Comment: Yes, it will remove them from Flickr as well. You either have to stick with using iPhoto (and be careful about changing names, etc) or remove them from Flickr and use something else like Flickr Uploadr. I didn't have a lot of photos on Flickr when i discovered this, so i removed then and used Flickr Uploadr. Could be a pain if you have a lot of photos though.

Comment: Yeah, I have thousands of photos on Flickr - perhaps a few hundred of which were uploaded with iPhoto '11, I was using the uploadr in previous versions of iPhoto. Okay, question answered; my next puzzle is how to do this without deleting photos from Flickr.

Comment: I think I have a solution: Removing permissions for iPhoto to make changes to your Flickr account before deleting the Flickr account in iPhoto seems to do the trick.

Comment: That sounds logical -- would love to know if it works!